# There is a chart library with v7 support?

Tags: android, charts, android-support-library

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/) (BTW, it is great!). My clients want to support android 2.1 devices (v7). I look for other visually nice libraries but I cant find any that matches this requirement.

Can you help me?

**v8+ Libraries known**

https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart v8
EazeGraph v9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look on this link:
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40

Comment: I found Androidplot through this site, with support from 1.6. `It’s designed from the ground up for Android,  compatible with all versions of Android from 1.6 onward and is used by over 500 apps on Google Play.`